# Disable Alt-h terminal mode key combination

Tags: neovim, nvchad

I would like to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> key combination that brings up the horizontal terminal in Neovim.

I see the original mapping in `~/.config/nvim/lua/core/mappings.lua`:

```
    ["<A-h>"] = {                                      
      function()                                       
        require("nvterm.terminal").toggle "horizontal" 
      end,                                             
      "Toggle horizontal term",                        
    },
```

This mapping is for normal mode (`n`).

I'm looking to add an override in `.config/nvim/lua/custom/init.lua`.

I've tried all sorts of approaches, using `unmap`, `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap`, `map <Esc-h> <Nop>`, and more, but I can't find something that works apart from commenting out the original code, which is not a good solution.

Any pointers appreciated.

Note - I have NVChad installed, if this has any impact.

Comment: Is it <Esc>-h or <Alt>-h?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt depending on the terminal, they might be equivalent.

Comment: Is uninstalling nvchad an acceptable solution? I assume  that’s where the original code came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add the following lines to:

~/.config/nvim/lua/custom/mapping.lua

```lua
-- more keybinds!
M.custom = {
  n = {
    ["<A-h>"] = {"<Nop>", ""}
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It's obvious now, and the best approach as far as I can see, consistent with the way the mapping is done in the first place. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-). If the solution fit your need maybe you can accept the answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest.